# Redirecting user after marker identification in AR.JS

Tags: javascript, ar.js

I want to redirect the user to a different page once the user has successfully identified the marker, is it possible to achieve this in AR.js

Answer (score 0):

try this. Give your `<a-marker>` id like `<a-marker id="marker" ...>`

```
<script>
//using jQuery
var marker = document.querySelector("#marker");
marker.addEventListener("markerFound", function (evt) {
    //marker found
    //do stuff
});

marker.addEventListener("markerLost", function (evt) {
    //marker lost
    //do stuff
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this redirect to a different page *<a-marker markerhandler ... >*

```
<script>
AFRAME.registerComponent('markerhandler', {
    init: function () {
      this.el.sceneEl.addEventListener('markerFound', () => {
        // redirect to custom URL e.g. google.com
        window.location = 'https://www.google.com/';
      })
    }
  });
</script>
```